# Ransack/Metawhere querystring length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have a Rails app, and it started like all Rails app, simple, with a searching function of first name and last name of users, now time has gone by, the user list has gotten very large, and the search has increased from a two field search to multiple field searching.

This created the problem of the query searching with MetaWhere is in the range of 10000+ characters. This has caused Nginx and HAProxy to break unless specific settings has been tweaked.

I am wondering what alternative solutions are there to solve this issue?

I thought about making the search a POST request, however, I am expecting pagination to work as well. Also the ability to "Copy and paste" the url.

Another potential solution is to encode the query string in database as a JSON blob, and then append a special hash for the query, but this has a lot of moving parts.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, so can you clarify? What is 10,000 characters? Why does it matter how big the user list is? What is your backend database?  :)